# Rails 6.0.6 + ApplicationRecord + Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It has been three years since I messed with one application of mine. It has always been working, and today, I noticed the following error after run “bundle install”:

---

### File 1 : product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :sell_unit
  belongs_to :currency
  has_many   :lots
  ...
```

---

### File 2 : currency.rb

```
class Currency < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  ...
```

---

### File 3 : lot.rb

```
class Lot < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :currency
  ...

  def register_new
    ...
    x = self.new   {:company_id=>2, 
            :product_id=>1, 
            :user_id=>2, 
            :price=>"10000.0", 
            :trigger_id=>2, 
            :label=>"dd1f7a132e59", 
            "quantity"=>"1", 
            "expires_at"=>"2022-10-25 19:44:13 +0100", 
            :currency_id=>1, 
            :state_id=>5, 
            :_active=>true, 
            :activation_pending=>true}

    x.save
```

Calling x.save => It produce the following instructions in order to proceed:

```
Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1
↳ app/models/lot.rb:54:in `register_new'

User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1
↳ app/models/lot.rb:54:in `register_new'
            
Currency Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `currencies`.* FROM `currencies` WHERE `currencies`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1
↳ app/models/lot.rb:54:in `register_new'



x.erros...
{:product=>["must exist"], :user=>["must exist"], :currency=>["must exist"]}
```

Why do the intermediate queries assume ID = NULL, if I even pass in the values?

```
`products`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1
`users`.`id` = NULL LIMIT 1
`currencies`.`id` = NULL
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough info in your post. What code is producing the SQL queries you have posted? I see the models in your post but not the code that causes the queries.

Comment: Well, when the code "x.save" is called, Under-the-Hood rails generate these 3 queries to perform the operation ("x.save").

(Please see the relationship between the tables... above)